# OpenACC in Visual Studion (Visual C++)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, openacc

I am very new in GPU. I want to write GPU in C++ by using OpenACC. I don't know how to add its libraries to the visual studio 2015. I've searched a lot in the Internet but couldnt find a good document to show the procedure. Could you please help me to fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio doesn't support OpenACC.  You'll need to either use GNU or PGI on Linux, or PGI on Windows.  Note that PGI doesn't support C++ on Windows. Hence, you'll want to write an OpenACC code in C and compile with "-ta=tesla:nordc".  Next create a library from the objects which can then be called from your Visual Studio built code.