# How to use OpenACC on windows

Tags: windows

I try to use OpenACC on windows(10), I installed mingw, and some ide(clion(automatically detect compiler) and many other) ,and this doesn't work,I try to install new version of mingw,but nothing happen, what i can do?I use C++ .

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [tour] and [ask].  Also try using Search before posting, I see several SO OpenAcc questions that mention Windows, one of which says you must use C not C++ - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44546806/openacc-in-visual-studion-visual-c

Comment: Yes I seen this question and  answer, but half of year been passed, i was thinking something change.But i open site OpenAcc and see that compiler gcc support openacc and i try to install mingw and using openacc.